# How To Save phpMyAdmin Tables On A Flash Drive

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I have had to re-install my wamp server after getting the message "access denied" when I tried to open phpMyAdmin to create new tables.I have then tried to copy the folder in which I saved the work relating to the tables I set up (before phpMyAdmin crushed) back to the www folder in the re-installed wamp server but I have been unsuccessful.
Is there a recognised method of saving  work one has done in phpMyAdmin to ,say, a flash drive for later retrieval?
If so, please let konw what this method is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backup mySQL databases from localhost running on Wamp server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989258/backup-mysql-databases-from-localhost-running-on-wamp-server)

Comment: There are many methods of backing up a MYSQL database, many tools that will do it. All that is required is a little research

Comment: You might like to start here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/backup-methods.html